# How to center grid items within a grid container - in material ui V5

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In MUI version 4, we have the following props (justifyContent & alignItems ) for centering the grid items as below:

```
<Grid
 container
 direction="row"
 justifyContent="center"
 alignItems="center"
>
```

However in the new MUI V5 release this is not working. How to get this in V5 ?

My Code is:

```
<Container
    maxWidth='lg'
    style={{ marginTop: "30px", marginBottom: "30px" }}
  >
   <Grid container spacing={4} justifyContent="center">
        {cards &&
          cards.map((item) => {
            return (

              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={item._id}>
                <Card style={{ maxWidth: "350px" }}>
                  //Code for the card
                </Card>
              </Grid>

            );
          })}
      </Grid>
</Container>
```

Comment: Where are your grid items code?

Comment: Added code, I am using.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-0q3cy?file=/demo.tsx)